# US B1/B2 Visa got rejected twice- visiting china previously will be problem

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, visa-refusals

Need your guidance in getting US visa B1/B2.

I am Rekha Jagadish, a house wife, and my husband is self-employed. Both of us are MBA graduates. We applied for US visa (tourism) but we were rejected twice under section 214. My sister-in-law is a house wife and her husband is a software engineer; they have lived in Dallas for the last 7 years. They sent an invitation and so we booked a Cosmos package for 8 days after which we planned to visit my sister-in-law's house and continue the trip along with her family.
We presented documents which includes the Cosmos package, a bank statement, property documents, my sister-in-law's husbands salary slip and return tickets.

My husband visited China 2 years before for about 12 days (business trip), and the interviewer cross-examined my husband regarding his visit. Is it going to be a problem in getting US visa? 
Please guide us where are we lacking behind. What else should we focus on?

Comment: Hi Rekha. Welcome to Travel.SE. Where do you live and what is your nationality?

Comment: I am not an expert on these immigration issues, but I expect a business trip to China would be a plus. Indicates your husband has a real business which can afford airfare to China, and also that he has a history of foreign travel from which he returns. One thing I am sure of: they are not interested in any political overtones of going to "Communist" China. That's anno 1965.

Comment: Section 214 what exactly? This is incomplete.

Comment: @MichaelHampton http://iran.usembassy.gov/visas/214b-refusal.html

Comment: @Karlson There are several sections of 214, and she didn't specify which one. So that's not necessarily helpful, unless you have somehow guessed correctly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't think any other apply: http://www.lawandsoftware.com/ina/INA-214-sec1184.html, http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/denials.html

Answer (score 2):

The refusal [under section 214](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/denials.html) is because you didn't prove to the satisfaction of the consular officer your definitive intent to return to the country of your origin.

From the limited information you have provided you seem to have no kids, who stay back, you don't have a job and your husband is self employed, which basically means that since he's traveling out of the country he can either work remotely or leave the business altogether, so there is very little tying you to your country of origin.

There is no real best solution for this problem but traveling alone and possibly with an organized tour might help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not point out what is section 214.

But from my years of experience with US Visas, they seem to have gotten concerned with your relatives base in the US and that you might try to settle there.

You might have been better off without showing that linkage. But now that you have been flagged twice, you might have to wait a bit to try again.

See if you can find out actual reasons for rejection under the so called 214.